# \envitem in ltxdockit package prints curly braces in a different font

Tags: fonts, documentation, ltxdockit

I've written a small LaTeX package and am preparing its documentation using `ltxdockit` package. I found a strange behavior about font.

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ltxdockit}
\begin{document}
\begin{ltxsyntax}
    \envitem{envname}[opt]{arg}

    this is an example.
\end{ltxsyntax}
\end{document}
```

After compiling this source with `pdflatex`, the result looks like this:

[image: result of MWE]

I noticed that the curly braces enclosing the beginning `envname` are rendered in `\rmfamily`, not in `\ttfamily`, which is weird to me.

I looked into `ltxdockit.sty` and found a macro `\ltd@envitem`, which `\envitem` is "`\let`ed" inside `ltxsyntax` environment.

```
\def\ltd@envitem#1{%
  \ltd@itembreak
  \item[\textbackslash begin]\{{\ltxsyntaxfont\ltxsyntaxlabelfont#1}\}%
  \ltd@pdfbookmark{#1}{#1}%
  \begingroup
  \ltd@syntaxsetup
  \ltxsyntaxfont
  \def\@tempa{%
    \ltd@itemsave
    \itemsep\z@
    \item[\textbackslash end]\{{\ltxsyntaxfont\ltxsyntaxlabelfont#1}\}%
    \ltd@itemrest}%
  \ltd@parseargs}
```

However, I cannot see differences between line 3 and line 11 above except for the `begin` and `end` and don't know why curly braces' in these parts look different with respect to font family.

How can I change the font of the first curly braces to `\ttfamily`? Although the package author says, "users should not at­tempt its use un­less they are ca­pa­ble of deal­ing with prob­lems un­aided", I'd appreciate it if you give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the begin and end is that `\{` picks up the current font which is typically roman at the start but monospace by the end.

Clearly that's not intended, here I change both begin and end lines to move the braces inside the scope of the font change.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ltxdockit}
\makeatletter
\def\ltd@envitem#1{%
  \ltd@itembreak
  \item[\textbackslash begin]{\ltxsyntaxfont\{{\ltxsyntaxlabelfont#1}\}}%
  \ltd@pdfbookmark{#1}{#1}%
  \begingroup
  \ltd@syntaxsetup
  \ltxsyntaxfont
  \def\@tempa{%
    \ltd@itemsave
    \itemsep\z@
    \item[\textbackslash end]{\ltxsyntaxfont\{{\ltxsyntaxlabelfont#1}\}}%
    \ltd@itemrest}%
  \ltd@parseargs}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{ltxsyntax}
    \envitem{envname}[opt]{arg}

    this is an example.
\end{ltxsyntax}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops, I gave the same trial before posting the question, but forgot `\makeatletter`. All things go well thanks!